# Ubuntu Studio Installer seems to cut off Pulseaudio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I am currently working in Ubuntu 20.04. I have attempted to load the Ubuntu Studio package over that. When I did that apparently cutoff Pulseaudio. So, I went into the repository ( synaptic package manager ) and removed it. My browser audio returned after I did. So, how should I modify the audio setup tab in Ubuntu Studio Controls so that Pulse Audio will run through JACK?

Comment: Default configuration of Ubuntu Studio Controls should route pulseaudio through jack. But sometimes I need to reload the browser-tab which is playing audio, that's my experience...

Answer (score 1):

Right after Ubuntu Studio is installed, the system has to be rebooted two or three times to make sure that the change is affected in the Linux kernel. Browser audio now plays